# how to generate onPause() event code

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need to make `onPause()` event in MainActivity class. Is it possible somehow generate souch kind of things automatically or I need to type evrything on keyboard?

currently my class looks like:

```
package com.example.llk;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this,"onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

There are onCreate and onCreateOptionsMenu events, but no onPause. Can IDE generate it automatically?

Comment: onPause() ll be handled by an android OS. you need to call onPause() in code and do your stuffs

Comment: I think your using eclipse juno latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question right, right click your code and select "Source" > "Override/implement methods" and under the Activity tab there should be a onPause() method, check it and click OK and Eclipse will generate the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can just write onPause() and Eclipse will suggest you but if you want to do it manually you can go through this way,

right click on your coding area **->** click on Source **->** click on Override/Implement Methods.. **->**
Click the arrow button to expand the "Activity" **->** make onPause() checked **->** Select Insertion Point for onPause() method as per your need **->** click on "OK" button.

*It is helpful to do it manually when you want to know about the various methods which are available for override.*

Answer (score 0):

[**Go to this android link. It ll show you. In eclipse you can't do automatically you have to do type everything from keyboard.**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html)

do like this programmatically

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);
//stuffs
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
     // your stuffs on pause what should be paused or stopped
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
     //your stuffs on resume
}
}
```

Comment: but I have no 'protected void onPause()'. Can IDE generate it automatically?

Comment: make it private or public.. I have to check that..